# Will the Bugzilla:Win32InstallPackages work on windows 2008 R2 64-bit?

Tags: bugzilla

Will the [Bugzilla:Win32InstallPackages](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32InstallPackages) work on windows 2008 R2 64-bit?

Comment: Have a look over here http://adamkett.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/bugzilla-on-windows-64bit-and-dbd-mysql.html

Comment: But i am actually using the unoffical installer which already included Perl. How do i know the Perl included in the installer is 32 bit version or 64 bit version?

Answer (score 1):

This should answerer you question

http://adamkett.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/bugzilla-on-windows-64bit-and-dbd-mysql.html

> I've installed Bugzilla a few times in the past on Microsoft machines
>   in the past, never really had any problems. I came to setup bugzilla
>   on a Windows 2003 R2 64-bit machine, already running IIS 6, MySQL 5.0
>   64 bit, windows setups are pretty simple from the Installing Bugzilla
>   on Microsoft Windows instructions provided.
>
> Grabbed a 64 bit version of active perl, installed and worked fine
>   from IIS, however when running the checksetup.pl I could not get "ppm>
>   install DBD-mysql" to work at all. When I manually specified theory58S
>   package URL manually the penny dropped with platform architecture not
>   supported.
>
> After some hunting around, found this post summerising what I had
>   suspected.
>
> Long and short of it use the Perl 32 bit version from active perl for
>   Bugzilla because the 64bit ActiveState version does not appear to
>   support the DBD-mysql.
>
> When running checksetup ignore the OCI.DLL not found unless you plan
>   to use Oracle instead of mysql.
>
> Noting there might be a 64bit version of DBD-mysql available for
>   windows & active perl somewhere but this solved my problem quickly.
>   -- Adam Kett

Comment: But i am actually using the unoffical installer which already included Perl. How do i know the Perl included in the installer is 32 bit version or 64 bit version?